# Generate two lists of random numbers to obtain a fixed sum

Tags: python, numpy, random

I need to generate two lists (let's call them X and Y) that sum to a specific number.

The function I need to create will take as inputs length of X and Y and the sum.

Then it creates random positive numbers for X and negative numbers for Y and normalizes them to sum to the number I want.

I've tried doing it like this:

```py
def extractAmount(ina, outa, balance):
    # ina: length of X, outa: length of Y, balance: the number I want
    valin = random.random((1, ina))  # X
    valout = -random.random((1, outa))  # Y
    val = np.concatenate([valin[0], valout[0]])
    valf = (np.round(val / abs(np.sum(val)) * abs(balance))).tolist() 
    return valf
```

The code works both for positive and negative numbers as `balance`, how could I improve it to work also if `balance == 0`?

If I do `extractAmount(2, 3, 100)`, the output is `[49.0, 350.0, -44.0, -68.0, -186.0]`, my problem is that if I do `extractAmount(2, 3, 0)`, it returns `[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]` while I need it to be random values, not all zeros.

Comment: I'm confused by what you really want. You said that the function takes the lengths of each list, but based on your code, ina is the maximum value of positive numbers and outa is the maximum value of negative numbers.

Comment: You should provide input/output examples

Comment: ina and outa are the length i want for X and Y (in the code valin and valout). By using random.random((1,3)) (as in ina=3) I obtain 3 random numbers in an array, am I wrong?

Comment: @DuccioBorchi are you using Python 2 or 3? The random module does not work that way for me. passing a tuple to random.random leads to an argument exception

Comment: Python 3 and it works for me

Comment: @mozway I provided one (correct) output and the one I don't want to have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need one more constraint for the problem to be well-defined. For example, you could require that the x values have a certain mean, say 200. Then you can first scale the random x values to meet that requirement, and then scale the random y values to meet the balance requirement in conjunction with x:

```py
import numpy as np

def extract_amount(length_x, length_y, mean_x, balance):
    x = np.random.random(length_x)
    x *= mean_x / np.mean(x)
    y = np.random.random(length_y)
    mean_y = (np.sum(x) - balance) / length_y
    y *= - mean_y / np.mean(y)
    return x, y

# Example 1
extract_amount(2, 3, 200, 100)
```

```
(array([224.47381339, 175.52618661]),
 array([-101.83346151, -181.49633185,  -16.67020665]))
```

```
# Example 2
extract_amount(2, 3, 200, 0)
```

```
(array([268.78299914, 131.21700086]),
 array([ -80.71742313, -125.50531378, -193.77726309]))
```

Comment: That could be a solution, the only problem is that I don't have a mean for x or y, I think maybe i could generate a number and then generate the others starting by the first one

Comment: But you would still need to input a constraint in how you generate that first number. If you don't have a mean, maybe you could justify some maximum value for the x items and use `np.random.randint` to generate x, without scaling?

Comment: Yes i did like that and it works, i used a `(random.random()*b_mean)/ina` where ina is the length of x and b_mean is the mean of all the balance (I have them stored in a dictionary before). So I think this is a good solution if you know a possible mean of one of the vector